# Navigationbar error in Cordova.js **callback.success.apply is not a function**

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, navigationbar

[Error occurred when i run **ionic cordova run android** first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDvLX.png)

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.1 (C:\Users\i3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.10.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 7 other plugins)
Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 (update available: 0.8.1)
   native-run  : 0.2.3 (update available: 0.2.9)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.10.2
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Navigation Bar Cordova Version
**"cordova-plugin-navigationbar": "^1.0.31",**

*Thank you for your support*